# Monoid of larger type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn haskell and reading the haskellbook.

In the book, the author mentioned larger type as follow:

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a, b)
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b, Monoid c) => Monoid (a, b, c)
```

> What these Monoids have in common is that they are giving you a new
>   Monoid for a larger type by reusing the Monoid instances of types that
>   represent components of the larger type.

What does he mean with larger datatype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the author means this: a tuple may contain some `Monoid` instance `a`, `b`, and `c`. However, we can view the `Monoid` instances in those tuples collectively, and thus define a new `Monoid` of type `(a, b, c)`. Thus, from 3 smaller `Monoid` instances grouped together in a tuple give rise to a "larger" `Monoid` instance over `(a, b, c)`.

Comment: It may also help to consider `a -> b` to be an `a`-ary product of `b`s. For instance, `Bool -> b` is isomorphic to `(b, b)`.